# What will happen to the Galilean moons after the Sun dies(assuming no human effects)

Tags: future, galilean-moons

Will the system go completely unstable due to all the mass loss the moons and jupiter experienced,will it already have gone unstable before this,or will they keep the resonance,if they keep it,will the moons just fall into jupiter one by one due to tidal dissipation?Or will they be ejected/have collided due to encounters before this?

Comment: Jupiter won't lose significant mass.

Comment: I'm doubtful the motions of the moons of Jupiter could be modeled with any useful accuracy on such a large timescale.

Comment: What do you mean by "sun dies"? There are various points at which you could define that death, and I think all are way past the furthest we would be likely able to predict the moons' motions